# How to troubleshoot Maven dependencies (e.g. in case of a ClassNotFoundException)

Tags: java, maven

(Answered Q&A-style)

Suppose you started encountering a `ClassNotFoundException` and you suspect it could be due to an outdated library. You discovered which library the not found class belongs to, however you have a non-trivial Maven project and the library isn't among explicitly declared dependencies. How can you find out which version of the offending library is being used?

Answer (score 2):

Start by outputting your project's dependency tree:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

You can focus on a particular project (e.g. if your Maven project is a multi-module one):

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -pl myproject
```

Now search for your library and discover the version being used in compilation, what depends on that library, and possibly why newer versions of the same library are being passed on. To use a tool of your choice to search in the tree, save the command output (on unix-like systems), then open it in the viewer of your choice.

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -pl myproject | tee deptree.txt
```

Comment: Or you could use the IDE....(Eclipse or IntelliJ support that. Netbeans I don't know).

Comment: `-Dverbose` should be used with care because it might result in wrong dependency trees.